# How to highlight cell in the table according to its value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a data from sql table [image: like this]

and i want to use java to get it to highlight high value cells to html like this
[image: like this]

I have created a table to put data in but can't get the value of each cell

```
                temphtml +="                    <tr>                                                                        \n";
                temphtml +="            <td> </td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td>0</td>              \n";    
                temphtml +="            <td>1</td>              \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td>2 </td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td>3</td>              \n";                                                                                    
                temphtml +="            <td>4</td>              \n";                                                                                    
                temphtml +="            <td>5</td>              \n";                                                                                       
                temphtml +="            <td>6</td>              \n";                                                                                  
                temphtml +="            <td>7</td>              \n";                                                                                         
                temphtml +="            <td>8</td>              \n";                                                                                         
                temphtml +="            <td>9</td>              \n";                                                                                         
                temphtml +="            <td>10</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td>11</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td>12</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td>13</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td>14</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td>15</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td >A</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'></td>             \n";        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A1'></td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A2'> </td>            \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A3'></td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A4'></td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A5'></td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A6'></td>             \n";                                                                                   
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A7'></td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A8'></td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A9'></td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A10'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A11'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A12'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A13'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A14'></td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A15'></td>            \n";        
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";                                                    
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td>B</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B0'></td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B1'></td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B2'></td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B3'></td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B4'></td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B5'></td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B6'></td>         \n";                                                                                       
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B7'></td>         \n";                                                                                              
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B8'></td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B9'></td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B10'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B11'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B12'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B13'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B14'></td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'B15'></td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C0</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C1</td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C2</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C3</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C4</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C5</td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C6</td>             \n";                                                                                   
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C7</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C8</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C9</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C10</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C11</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C12</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C13</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C14</td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>C15</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D0</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D1</td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D2</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D3</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D4</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D5</td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D6</td>             \n";                                                                                   
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D7</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D8</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D9</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D10</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D11</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D12</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D13</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D14</td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>D15</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E0</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E1</td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E2</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E3</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E4</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E5</td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E6</td>             \n";                                                                                   
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E7</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E8</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E9</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E10</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E11</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E12</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E13</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E14</td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>E15</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F0</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F1</td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F2</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F3</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F4</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F5</td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F6</td>             \n";                                                                                   
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F7</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F8</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F9</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F10</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F11</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F12</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F13</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F14</td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>F15</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G0</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G1</td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G2</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G3</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G4</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G5</td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G6</td>             \n";                                                                                   
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G7</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G8</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G9</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G10</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G11</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G12</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G13</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G14</td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>G15</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="        </tr>                                                             \n";
                temphtml +="        <tr>                                                              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H</td>              \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H0</td>             \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H1</td>             \n";                                                                                      
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H2</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H3</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H4</td>             \n";                                                                                     
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H5</td>             \n";                                                                                        
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H6</td>             \n";                                                                                   
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H7</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H8</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H9</td>             \n";                                                                                          
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H10</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H11</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H12</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H13</td>            \n";                                                                                           
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H14</td>            \n";
                temphtml +="            <td id = 'A0'>H15</td>              \n";                                                                                                        
                  
                temphtml +="                    </tr>                                                        \n";
```

How do I style each cell?

Comment: Edit the question here. with proper coding styles.

Comment: `id = 'A0'` can be used only once, an ID is unique. You may use `class = 'A0'` so it can be reused as much you need it. Beside i do not clearly understand your question, `temphtml` does not match the screens you added.  Can you clarify ?

Comment: JAVA or JAVASCRIPT ?

Comment: Could you have a good look at the code you have shown (which I assume is Javascript) and see what table with what content it produces. It has some resemblance to the image you have given, but not much. Also, where are the values from the database put into the table, is that in the backend somewhere (e.g. through PHP on a server)?

Comment: What's Java got to do with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the `id` you are using to `class = 'A0'` so by manipulating the HTML values via Javascript you can colour the cells

```
var items =document.getElementsByClassName('A0');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if(items[i].innerHTML>0){
      items[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: #F00');
  }
}
```

So here what happens is it will get all values of the elements which contains `class='A0'` and check if the values are greater than 0 and if it is it will colour the HTML element `text-color`. if wants to change the background color just replace `color` with `background-color`